# What are the valid platform values for metadata.rb's supports key?

Tags: chef-infra

In [metadata.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_metadata.html), there is a `supports` key that lets you tell chef which OS/versions the cookbook is compatible with.

What are the valid values for the OS/platform?  I tend to just scrabble the information together from various examples I find on the web.  For instance, I found a pretty exhaustive list, but I'd like to know how the values were derived:

```
supports 'amazon'
supports 'centos'
supports 'debian'
supports 'fedora'
supports 'freebsd'
supports 'mac_os_x'
supports 'oracle'
supports 'redhat'
supports 'scientific'
supports 'solaris2'
supports 'suse'
supports 'ubuntu'
supports 'windows'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking:

```
    %w{aix amazon arch centos chefspec debian dragonfly4 fedora freebsd gentoo
       ios_xr mac_os_x nexus omnios openbsd opensuse oracle raspbian redhat
       slackware smartos solaris2 suse ubuntu windows}
```

Or at least thats every platform that fauxhai recognizes.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK those values are only informational. No cookbook will refuse to run on a platform which is not mentioned there.